# How to solve android retrofit post image error 500

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

So I tried to upload image with multipart but i received 500 error code. I've tried it on postman and it worked well and it worked too with this code but without image. Am I wrong at multipart thing?

ApiService
[image: ApiService]

Filepath
[image: Filepath]

MediaType
[image: MediaType]

Swagger
[image: Swagger]

Answer (score 0):

I think Scoped storage issue. Stream the file using input stream.

Try like below

```
contentResolver.openInputStream(it)?.use { inputStream ->
val tempFile = createTempFile(this, fileName, extension)
copyStreamToFile(it, tempFile)
val filePath = tempFile.absolutePath

val requestFile: RequestBody = File(filePath).asRequestBody(fileType?.toMediaTypeOrNull())
val body: MultipartBody.Part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", fileName, requestFile)
```

}